# Using Translator in openpyxl to copy formulae

Tags: python, excel, formula, openpyxl

I need to copy a formula from a programmatically determined column to an adjacent column and need the formula cell reference to 'move' with the column. For example, in cell E2 is the formula `='Copy ATDs'!B60` and I need to copy the formula to cell F2 as `='Copy ATDs'!C60`
The example in the documentation is as follows (sic):

```
>>> from openpyxl.formula.translate import Translator
>>> ws['F2'] = "=SUM(B2:E2)"
>>> # move the formula one colum to the right
>>> formula = Translator("=SUM(B2:E2)", "G2")
'=SUM(C2:F2)'
```

I understand this to mean that the Translator function will return a formula that is transposed by one column if the second argument is moved one column.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
new_cell_ref = ws_dt.cell(column=source_col, row=r).offset(row=0, column=1).address()
ws_dt.cell(column=new_col, row=r).value = \
    Translator(ws_dt.cell(column=source_col, row=r).value, \ 
               new_cell_ref.column + str(new_cell_ref.row)).tokenizer.formula
```

The Translator function doesn't seem to care a whit what the second argument is.  It consistently returns the original formula without translating anything. Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do `print(ws_dt.cell(column=source_col, row=r).value)` and compare it with the doc example. Also `print(new_cell_ref.column + str(new_cell_ref.row)`. [Edit] your Question and explain **why** do you use `.tokenizer.formula`?

Comment: Your code is too convoluted, break it down in multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is slightly opaque, but you use the Translator class to set where the formula is currently, and then the translate_formula method to actually translate it

Translator(formula, current_cell).translate_formula(target_cell) == formula_translated

```
Translator('=A1+B1', 'C1').translate_formula('C2') == '=A2+B2'
```

You then assign that new formula to the cell value.